# Subspaces of quotients of $L^p$ spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Is the collection of subspaces of quotients of $L^p$ spaces considered to be a large class of Banach spaces?

Answer (score 2):

These are called $SQ_p$ spaces. The size varies: for $p=1,\infty$ the class is perhaps **too** large (includes all separable spaces); for $p=2$ it consists only of the Hilbert space. In between, these spaces have interesting structure related to factorization of operators. They are often called *subquotients* of $L^p$. Some references:

1. S. Kwapien, [On operators factorizable through $L^p$ space](https://eudml.org/doc/94614), Mémoires de la Société Mathématique de France 31-32 (1972): 215-225.
2. Y. Gordon and P. Saphar, [Ideal norms on $E\otimes L^p$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256049412), Illinois J. Math.
   Volume 21, Issue 2 (1977), 266-285.
3. G. Pisier, [Complex Interpolation Between Hilbert, Banach and Operator Spaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=g5_UAwAAQBAJ), Memoirs of the AMS, 2010. Preprint available from [ArXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0476).

Kwapien's paper has been influential, but a little hard to read now  that we're spoiled by $\LaTeX$. Gordon-Saphar is in the same spirit but LaTeX'd. Pisier's memoir shows how these spaces naturally come up in the theory of interpolation.